EAS expo build failed du loading assets JSON from Metro
Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. SHA-1 for file /home/expo/workingdir/build/global.css.android.js is not computed.
Error: @build-script-error-begin
Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. SHA-1 for file /home/expo/workingdir/build/global.css.android.js is not computed.
Potential causes:
1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
2) Check blockList in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
@build-script-error-end
at createManifestForBuildAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/utils/build/createManifestForBuildAsync.js:44:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/utils/build/createUpdatesResources.js:26:5
